# Why is the text position different when multiline is set to true. Can this be avoided?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a form with multiple TextBox controls. Some have multiline set to true others to no. When using large fonts it becomes obvious that the text positioning is different. When multiline is true some kind of additional margin appears around the text.
The following code fragment

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = "Test";
textBox.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 16);
Console.WriteLine("Single Line:" + textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0));
textBox.Multiline = true;
Console.WriteLine("Multi Line:" + textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0));
```

outputs
Single Line:{X=1,Y=0}
Multi Line:{X=7,Y=1}

My questions are:
Why is this margin added in multiline mode?
Can this be avoided/controlled?

I already found out that the text in multiline mode is drawn with

```
TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping
```

while in single line mode

```
TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine
```

is used.
Is there a way to control the TextFormatFlags used by the TextBox?

Thank you for any effort you put on answering my questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your own class derived from TextBox and handle the Paint event by overriding OnPaint.

In there you will have full control over how the text is rendered for the TextBox using the proper TextFormatFlags as desired.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that with overriding OnPaint for a TextBox I'll run into more problems. I did this before and had a lot of strange effects.

Comment: Of course you need to make sure that you don't do anything silly in there, but other than handling this yourself, I don't see how you could change the TextFormatFlags that are used by the standard TextBox. Might be worth looking at the default implementation in Reflector or other disassembler

Comment: Again thank you for your help. I'll mark your post as answer as it was the most helpful one.
I solved the displacement of the text by putting the TextBox on a Panel and use the negative values of the displacement as location.
This works as my TextBox has no border.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I'm not sure of it seems Segoe UI will offset your characters in the multiline textbox.Microsof Sans Serif does not have the same problem.

My suggestion: Try using another font.

Comment: The users can choose the font so this is not an option. Also with Microsof Sans Serif there is still a vertical offset of one pixel though independent of the font size.